# Getting the public link of the uploaded file on Google Cloud Storage from Go Runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Im able to create and write into file on Google Cloud from the Go Runtime , but not able to figure out a way to make the file public and get the public link of the file . Any idea on how to get the public link of the file using Go Runtime ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the public link without requesting it in code.

Do you know the name of the file and the bucket where you are saving it?

If the answer is yes, you can easily construct the full (public) URL. For example, if you bucket is `bucket123` and your file name is `sample.txt` the final URL will be:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket123/sample.txt
```

In order to make the file public, you can use the Google Cloud Storage API. [This link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-go-samples) contains several examples in Go.

(Look specifically for `predefinedAcl='publicRead'` in the `insert` API call)